# What is the difference between comma (,) and plus (+) in string arrays?

Tags: c#, string

```
string[] NamesList = new string[3]
{
   "George", "Bob", "Kat"
};       
Console.WriteLine("Name list: ",String.Join(",", NamesList));
```

On the last line, If I replace the first comma with +, I get the following results:

> Name list: George, Bob, Kat

If I leave it as It is (with comma), there is nothing shown:

> Name list:

Comment: This has nothing to do with the array, but rather with [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The reason nothing is shown in case of `,` is that there is no placeholder in your string whose value will be replaced with the evaluated value of `String.Join(",", NamesList)`

Comment: when you do `"Name list: " + String.Join(",", NamesList)` it joins `Name List : "` and the string generated from `String.Join`.  When you replace `+` with comma, you are actually passing two arguments to Console.WriteLine where second arguments is supposed to be the value to placed in the placeholder provided in the first argument. So if you want this to work with comma you need to change it to `"Name list: {0}",String.Join(",", NamesList)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name list: " + String.Join(",", NamesList));
```

you concatenate everything.

With that line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name list: ", String.Join(",", NamesList));
```

you get nothing after `"Name list :"` because the right syntax is :

```
Console.WriteLine("Name list: {0}", String.Join(",", NamesList));
```

That take the parameters after the first ',' in the `{0}`, `{1}` etc...